# Exclude "'" in pipeline Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, grok

I am currently working with Kibana and am running into a problem which i cant solve.
in my source file there is a rule which includes "", however when i run the script i made for kibana in dev tools it does not include that rule bur gives a error. how can i exclude those characters or how can it be included?
i have tried to exclude those characters using a g sub field but that doesn't work either.

```
"%{DATA:Datetime},%{DATA:Elapsed},%{DATA:label},%{DATA:ResponseCode},%{DATA:ResponseMessage},%{DATA:ThreadName},%{DATA:DataType},%{DATA:Success},%{DATA:FailureMessage},%{DATA:Bytes},%{DATA:SentBytes},%{DATA:GRPThreads},%{DATA:AllThreads},%{DATA:URL},%{DATA:Latency},%{DATA:IdleTime},%{GREEDYDATA:Connect}"
```

that is the grok pattern i'm using.

```
27-19-2018 12:19:43,8331,OK - Refresh Samenvatting,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 67, number of failing samples : 0",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,550720,137198,1,1,null,8318,5094,270
```

and this is the line i want to run trough it, it goes wrong at the "".

R. Kiers

Answer (score 0):

Best to use custom patterns. Tested on Kibana 6.x and works for the sample data provided above. Can easily tweak to work with any sample data

custom patterns used:

`UNTILNEXTCOMMA ([^,]*)`

Grok pattern:

```
%{DATA:Datetime},%{NUMBER:Elapsed},%{UNTILNEXTCOMMA:label},%{NUMBER:Responsecode},"%{GREEDYDATA:ResponseMessage}",%{UNTILNEXTCOMMA:ThreadName},%{UNTILNEXTCOMMA:DataType},%{UNTILNEXTCOMMA:Success},%{UNTILNEXTCOMMA:FailureMessage},%{NUMBER:Bytes},%{NUMBER:SentBytes},%{NUMBER:GRPThreads},%{NUMBER:AllThreads},%{UNTILNEXTCOMMA:URL},%{NUMBER:Latency},%{NUMBER:IdleTime},%{NUMBER:Connect}
```

**EDIT1:**

Pipeline for Kibana 5.x

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/test
{
    "description": "Test pipeline",
    "processors": [
      {
        "grok": {
          "field": "message",
          "patterns": [
            "%{DATA:Datetime},%{DATA:Elapsed},%{DATA:label},%{DATA:ResponseCode},\"%{GREEDYDATA:ResponseMessage}\",%{DATA:ThreadName},%{DATA:DataType},%{DATA:Success},%{DATA:FailureMessage},%{DATA:Bytes},%{DATA:SentBytes},%{DATA:GRPThreads},%{DATA:AllThreads},%{DATA:URL},%{DATA:Latency},%{DATA:IdleTime},%{GREEDYDATA:Connect}"
          ],
          "ignore_failure": false
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Tested using simulate and it works

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/test/_simulate
{
  "docs" : [
    { "_source": { "message" : "27-19-2018 12:19:43,8331,OK - Refresh Samenvatting,200,\"Number of samples in transaction : 67, number of failing samples : 0\",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,550720,137198,1,1,null,8318,5094,270"
} }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't work on kibana 5.x which i'm currently running.

Comment: Also it is just the field ResponseMessage that has that problem

Comment: Are you trying to create an ingest pipeline to parse your data ? If yes, see my edit above and see if it works for you.